# Getting a Context from a NativeActivity

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk, native-activity

I have an application using NativeActivity. I want to call out into Java to do something that requires a Context (e.g., accessing TelephonyManager to query the IMEI).

How do I get a valid Context for my activity?

The ANativeActivity structure contains a variety of useful data for my application, such as the JavaVM, and JNI environment, etc. It also contains a jobject pointing at my NativeActivity's class object. What it doesn't contain is a jobject pointing at the NativeActivity's *instance*. I don't see anything useful in `struct android_app`, either.

It must be possible to do this; any ideas how?

Comment: Possible double question. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449864/access-android-context-in-ndk-application

Comment: Nope, that question refers to old-style NDK (where it was strictly call-out from Java), while I'm using new-style NativeActivity NDK (where the main app is written in native code and calls into Java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite its name the `clazz` member of `ANativeActivity` struct is actually pointing to `android.app.NativeActivity` instance.
Check [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20130331010259/http://blog.tewdew.com/post/6852907694/using-jni-from-a-native-activity) for an example of using a JNI call from the Native Activity to Java code.

Comment: The docs in the header say it's a class, too --- but yes, now I actually try to use it it's obviously the instance rather than the class. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's true. The doc is a confusing one as it describes clazz field as `The NativeActivity Java class`. The only weak hint is `clazz` type: `jobject` instead of `jclass`. Nevertheless it's worth a bug/feature-request for docs improvement to be posted.