# Manage Android application settings from C rather than Java?

Tags: java, android, c, api, application-settings

Could I manage Android application settings from C rather than Java?

I mean the settings that I could manage:

- *for Android, in Java* - through `android.content.SharedPreferences` interface;
- *for iOS, in C* - through utilities from `CoreFoundation/CFPreferences.h`;
- *for Windows, in C* - through WinAPI for Registry management;
- *for Android, in C* - ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it will be messy. In Android, you can use the NDK to access the sharedPreferences via JNI. See:

[Access android context in ndk application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449864/access-android-context-in-ndk-application)

Comment: Thanks. I know about JNI. So this is what I've been considering a solution unless there exists a direct C API to do it.

Comment: There is no other API as far as I know. The JNI is your best bet.