# How to get the Android context instance when calling JNI method?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native-code

I have already read some relevant answers on stackoverflow,but seems no one has answered my question.I will get the android ID from native code,i.e. calling the method getAndroidIDfromNativeCode in C code,(so the JVM is inited in the native code by method create_vm),you know that when calling the method **getContentResolver**,you must use a **Android Context instance** to call it,so how to get this **Context instance**?

```
    static jstring
    native_code_getAndroidID(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
    {
        jclass c_settings_secure = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/provider/Settings$Secure");
        jclass c_context = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/Context");
        if(c_settings_secure == NULL || c_context == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        //Get the getContentResolver method
        jmethodID m_get_content_resolver = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_context, "getContentResolver",
                                                               "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
        if(m_get_content_resolver == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        //Get the Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID constant
        jfieldID f_android_id = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, c_settings_secure, "ANDROID_ID", "Ljava/lang/String;");

        if(f_android_id == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        jstring s_android_id = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, c_settings_secure, f_android_id);

        //create a ContentResolver instance context.getContentResolver()
        /*
          where can I get the context instance from Anroid APP??
        */
        jobject o_content_resolver = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, m_get_content_resolver);
        if(o_content_resolver == NULL || s_android_id == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        //get the method getString
        jmethodID m_get_string = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, c_settings_secure, "getString",
                                                           "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

        if(m_get_string == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        //get the Android ID
        jstring android_id = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, c_settings_secure,
                                                            m_get_string,
                                                            o_content_resolver,
                                                            s_android_id);
        return android_id;
    }

    JNIEnv* create_vm() {
      JavaVM* jvm;
      JNIEnv* env;
      JavaVMInitArgs args;
      JavaVMOption options[1];

      /* There is a new JNI_VERSION_1_4, but it doesn't add anything for the purposes of our example. */
      args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
      args.nOptions = 1;
      options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=-jar-path";
      args.options = options;
      args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

      JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
      return env;
    }

    char *jstringTostr(jstring android)
    {
      ...
    }

    //I will call this function from native code.

    char *getAndroidIDfromNativeCode()
    {

      JNIEnv* env = NULL;

      env = create_vm();
      jstring androidID = native_code_getAndroidID(env,NULL);
      return jstringTostr(androidID);

    }
```

Comment: Just curious, how many native code are you deploying for different Android archs?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto just improve some android media player native codes,it is open source，there are a lot.

Comment: What i meant is that i myself know of at least 2 different archs for Android: Intel Atom and ARM7+... You plan to provide your native code for each of them?

Comment: there are 5 provided by open source codes,arm64,armv5,armv7a x86,x86_64 ,and I only update codes for armv7a.

Answer (score 7):

The following method can get a **Context instance**.

```
static jobject getGlobalContext(JNIEnv *env)
{   
    jclass activityThread = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/app/ActivityThread");
    jmethodID currentActivityThread = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, activityThread, "currentActivityThread", "()Landroid/app/ActivityThread;");
    jobject activityThreadObj = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, activityThread, currentActivityThread);
    
    jmethodID getApplication = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, activityThread, "getApplication", "()Landroid/app/Application;");
    jobject context = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, activityThreadObj, getApplication);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work for service classes that are not in the same process as the main activity.

Comment: @void.pointer I used the above codes under single process program, and have not done some tests on multi-processes program yet.So what about get the context instance in the main activity process and pass the value to other processes?

Comment: If I call this method in `JNI_OnLoad` and the `System.loadLibrary()` is under the `attachBaseContext()` of Application class, the `context` will be NULL. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of type `jobject` is the instance of the class in which you are keeping the Native method declaration.

So if you declare your method inside an activity, you can directly use the last parameter `thiz` as an instance of your context.

Otherwise you will need to add another parameter of type `Context` in your native declaration and of type `jobject` in the method defination.

Comment: sorry,what I mean is that what value should I pass to jobject or the "another parameter";when java call c ,we can get the thiz automatically,but when c call java,we need to pass the parameter ourselves.