# Get context in JNI_OnLoad?

Tags: android, android-context, jnienv

I want to call function from JNI_Onload with passing context as parameters. How to get context in JNI_OnLoad?

```
JavaVM *_glJvm;

void myfunction(jObject context) {

}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *e;

    _glJvm = jvm;
    if (jvm->GetEnv((void **) &e, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    
    jobject context = ? // how to get context?
    myfunction(context);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871051/13912132

Comment: @JCWasmx86, I got the message Cannot find class: android/app/ActivityThread, I ignored that. But getGlobalContext() is worked. Thanks.