# How to read shared preferences from Android NDK C++ code?

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, android-ndk, sharedpreferences

I'd like to read shared preferences from C++ code directly. Is that possible?

Any piece of code for that ? Thanks.

Here's what I would transcript to C++ :

```
val sharedPref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("OF_IR", MODE_PRIVATE)
val paramFromPref = sharedPref.getString("parameter", "")
if (paramFromPref != "") {

}
```

Comment: Certainly possible but not recommended. Native code should do native work, let Android work in Android code. Anyway you can do it via JNI as usual. `env->FindClass("android/content/SharedPreferences")`, `env->GetMethodID(cls, "getSharedPreferences", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;");`, `env->CallObjectMethod(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call Kotlin function from JNI easily.
Here is JNI Docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

You can find method for FindClass, GetMethodId, CallVoidMethod, etc.

Here is example for read sharedpreferences.

```
jclass jcContext = env->FindClass("android/content/Context");
jclass jcSharedPreferences = env->FindClass("android/content/SharedPreferences");

if(jcContext==nullptr || jcSharedPreferences== nullptr){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SharedPreferences","Cannot find classes");
}

jmGetString=env->GetMethodID(jcSharedPreferences,"getString","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
jmethodID jmGetSharedPreferences=env->GetMethodID(jcContext,"getSharedPreferences","(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;");
joSharedPreferences=env->CallObjectMethod(androidContext,jmGetSharedPreferences,env->NewStringUTF(name),MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try that as soon as possible, but this must work from the C++ class (not the JNI code)...

Comment: How to get androidContext ?

Comment: Here is answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871051/10247147

Comment: I'll try that... Thanks