# Get Activity Context in JNI to pass it to a java function call

Tags: java, android, c++, mobile, java-native-interface

**Project Info:**

I have an Android Java SDK and a C++ wrapper project. The C++ wrapper is an Android Java app that loads a C++ library which uses an *aar* of the SDK in order to access and use some of the functions it provides. JNI is used to achieve the mapping and translation of the Java functions so that the C++ functions can call them.

**Application Context:**

I know that in JNI, you can get the Application Context by doing something like described in [How to get the Android context instance when calling JNI method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869901/). I've actually successfully done something similar to acquire the Application Context and pass it as a parameter in a Java function using JNI.

**Activity Context:**

Now, there's an SDK function that takes an Activity Context as a parameter and uses it to run a block of code on the UI thread. Unfortunately, this functionality can't change.

**Question:**

Is there any way to get the Activity Context with JNI in a similar manner as how you get the Application Context in the link above? Otherwise, is there any other way you can get an Activity Context using JNI so as to later pass it as an argument to a Java function call?

Answer (score 1):

JNI methods could be called passing "jobject" Context as one of their arguments, then you can use that variable INSIDE that method all many times you need. JOBJECT accepts ANY kind of data, so I think you need to do some Type check....

- JNI method: Java_com_example_test_method(env, jobject context, jint arg1);
- Java method: native method(Context context, int arg1);

So from the Activity you have to call a JNI method and pass "this" as "jobject". Then if you need the Context outside THAT specific JNI method, you need to convert that jobject to a JNI GlobalRef.